# How to upload a Video in back4app

Tags: flutter, dart, back4app

so I‘m working with flutter and Back4App and I want to Upload Videos from the Gallery or from the Camera to Back4App. I couldn‘t find a tutorial to it online so I‘m kinda stuck. And help is much appreciated!

Also I can already choose videos from the Gallery or take Videos with the camera but after that my App crashes and the Video wont show in my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you tagged back4app, I would recommend you take a look at this guide: https://www.back4app.com/docs/flutter/parse-sdk/flutter-save-file

Comment: Yes I did but it is only a tutorial for pictures.